# Cleaning correlation matrix, Bun Bouchaud Potters (2016) method

Tags: correlation-matrix, random-matrix-theory

Stock returns correlation matrices are notoriously hard to estimate, especially when the number of assets $N$ is large with respect to the size of the readily available historical returns $T$. Many methods exist to ease the estimation (and work-around the problem's ill-posedness).

I wondered if anyone tried to implement the unbiased version of the Rotational Invariant correlation matrix Estimator (RIE) described in [this](https://www.cfm.fr/assets/ResearchPapers/Cleaning-Correlation-Matrices.pdf) paper.

I've written some python code to test it and it does not seem to offer a significant advantage over the standard sample estimator of the correlation matrix.

I've already checked my code several time so I'd be interested to know if someone managed to implement it adequately (I don't need the code, just to know whether there is a typo in the paper for instance).

Thanks a lot already.

Comment: I am seeing similar results, and am wondering if perhaps I am misinterpreting something or if there is a typo in the paper etc. Do you have python code that you would like to share to compare notes. I'm happy to provide R code.

Comment: @user30925, could you please provide your R code?

Comment: Are you using it to estimate the covariance matrix or for Markovitz allocation? For estimating the covariance matrix, the naive estimator is better as it is unbiased.

Comment: I reach the same results. @user30925, could you please provide your R code? Thanks in advance

Comment: I implemented and am testing it. Does the "cleaned" matrix have 1's in the diagonal for you? Looking at the paper it looks to me like there's no reason to think it should (and reasons to think it shouldn't, but I want to confirm). The estimator doesn't preserve the sum of the eigenvalues. Hard to check that from eq 7 in the paper, but in eq 10 you multiply by max(1, ...), so either one or both won't preserve the trace. So it begs the question: if this produces a cleaned correlation matrix that is no longer a correlation matrix, how do you use it?

Comment: I don't mean that rhetorically. Are you meant to actually use this directly on a covariance matrix? In which case this will modify your vols. Is that desired?

Also, on the matter of typos in the paper, if you look at Bun & Knowles 2018, there appear to be pretty big differences in the formulae, unless I misunderstood something.